# Higher levet at Index with imakeidx package?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I have a problem about make higher level at Index with imakeidx package , as far as know Index with imakeidx package have chapter level. You can see my MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=What?,intoc]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
a\index{a}
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

**How to change from chapter level to part level ?**

Comment: Instead of `title=?`, add `\indexsetup{level=\part}`.

Comment: @Werner , ok it's very perfect ,

Comment: @Werner, one question again, How to change from  glossary level to chapter level ?

Comment: What is "glossary level"? Are you interested in making the glossary *also* become a `\part`?

Comment: @Yes, I interested in making the glossary also became a \part.